# Миниатюра в вордпрес

Tags: wordpress

Можно ли в вордпрес сделать миниатюру записи что бы она отображалась в процентном отношении а  не в пиксельном

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через css, ставь нужное значение в % и !important если надо.